Difference in reading 4-20mA sensor with voltage divider/opamp/current sensing IC?
I'm in dilemma on building a proper or best way to reading any industrial 4-20mA sensor. Throughout the research, I found out several ways to do so, either the easiest way by reading the voltage of a shunt resistor across it (voltage divider or simply ohm law method), or the sensor input feed into an opamp circuit to amplify and convert into voltage output, or input goes into a current sensing IC such as TP5551  or INA196?? The output voltage should be read by a MCU or ADC chip.
Some said even most of the branded PLC are done by using merely a 250 Ω resistor which will generate 5 V at 20 mA, yet not any complicated opamp or current sensing circuit.

This question seems as a duplicate. You can see a similar question here: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/166301/using-a-microcontroller-adc-to-measure-a-4-20ma-sensor. You would convert that current to an ADC voltage. Look for solutions in that link.

Thanks for the heads up!! Meanwhile, my question is among various solutions, which approach is the best method to reading an industrial 4-20mA sensor, into a MCU or an ADC?

Please define your criteria for "easy", "good", "efficient". The most simple (and easiest, best, most efficient) way is a shunt, at the microcontroller you use an ADC in any case.

As Andy_aka wrote that you would need a precision registor to convert that current into a voltage. Instead of using one resistor , you may use a combination of resistors to get a known impedance.within acceptable range of error and with that you can convert the current into voltage.

What's "best" depends entirely on what comes next in the signal path. There may be a dozen different ways that you can measure and process sensor current, but I'll describe a couple of reasons you might choose some technique other than a simple resistor.
Using a single shunt resistance \$R_S\$ to develop a voltage (that you intend to measure) will yield a voltage signal with source impedance \$R_S\$, which will be loaded by whatever you connect to it. Typically \$R_S\$ is hundreds of ohms.
To ensure at least \$X\%\$ accuracy, you'll need the input impedance of the following stage to exceed \$\frac{100}{X}R_S\$. Most MCU ADC inputs are very high impedance, well over 1MΩ, so this isn't usually a problem. Here the ADC has 10kΩ input impedance, and the voltmeter shows how this has affected signal potential, which we would expect to be \$20mA \times 150\Omega = 3V\$:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
The solution might be to buffer the signal with an op-amp follower:

simulate this circuit
A transimpedance amplifier (TIA) offers an additional benefit:

simulate this circuit
While the signal inversion may be inconvenient, it does still buffer, providing an accurate output \$V_{OUT}=-I \times R_1\$ in spite of the heavy load \$R_{LOAD}\$. The most interesting behavioural quirk of this TIA is that input potential is held near 0V, which helps when the 4-20mA source has limited compliance voltage. Notice how output potential is far greater (in magnitude) than the 5V maximum compliance voltage of the current source.
You might require galvanic isolation of the input source from the measurement circuitry and its ADC, in which case you would employ a completely different system, an example of which is described here.
Lastly, using a simple resistor yields a voltage range that doesn't get near to 0V. For example, using 165Ω you can expect potentials between \$4mA \times 165\Omega=+0.66V\$ and \$20mA \times 165\Omega=+3.3V\$. This doesn't cover the full input range of a 3.3V ADC, and while you can compensate for this deficit in software, you will lose some of the ADC's full digital range. To mitigate that, you might use an op-amp to scale and offset the signal:

simulate this circuit


Thank you very much for your answer, by far the most helpful and insightful response! Like you had said, nowadays MCU and ADC chip inputs are very high impedence, mostly 1MΩ. Thus, that's why we are seeing some PLC analog inputs are using just a simple shunt resistor to get the reading from the 4/20mA signal??
IF, the ADC input impedence is low (less than 100k ohm?), then opamp follower circuit should be the best solution, to counter the internal input impedence, am i correct??

If a simple shunt resistance with no other "tweaks"  is usable, then there's no reason not to go that route. PLC equipment mostly has close to 12V or 24V compliance for their 4-20mA outputs, so the TIA is likely unnecessary. Because of the 0-4mA "gap" absent from the signal, an op-amp voltage follower isn't even required to get its output down to 0V, requiring no negative supply, and making it the cheapest and easiest solution in most cases where a single shunt resistor won't do. I still hesitate to call it the "best", because every application is different.

Yup, most of the sensor in the market works with 24V, and either output 4-20mA or 0-10V...Agree on the 0-4mA gap absent from the signal, which most of the time doesnt require to pull it down to 0V, while maintaining it above 0V, we can monitor if the sensor is working/absence or shorted.

Whatever way you look at it, the 4/20 mA signal will be applied to either a shunt resistor directly or, indirectly via an op-amp or high-side sensor chip.
Given that all solutions will require at least one fairly precision resistor to make it work, any circuit that adds extra errors due to silicon devices getting in the way of the signal are bound to be both a little less accurate and a little more expensive.

Indeed, i'm aware that more complex circuitry will add extra errors and more expensive! While a simple shunt resistor will do the work, I'm not sure whether it is the best and efficient way? Some use opamp, some just use current sensor IC, and output to MCU.

They all use a sense resistor. Did you read my answer carefully @KennyThum

I'm believe that you answer it with 4/20mA current signal applied to a "shunt resistor" directly; A shunt resistor is a sense resistor, apologize if i'm wrong...

@KennyThum yes, a shunt resistor is a current sense resistor.
